# Windowsでのキー入力の仕組みについて

Tags: c++, windows-10

WindowsアプリケーションをC++で開発しています。

キーイベントを取得するには、まずはWM_KEYDOWNを取得。
もっと早く知りたい場合は、グローバルフック。
さらに早く知りたい場合は、KeyboardFilterDriverを開発...

このようにしてWindowsのキー入力について深堀してきたのですが、ハードからのキー入力をどのようにソフトで処理しているのか、一連の流れがつかめません。
ハードからカーネル、ドライバ、ユーザーランド、ユーザーアプリケーション....といったキー入力の一連の流れを詳しく教えてはいただけないでしょうか。

目的は、ユーザーランド側（システムではない方）でいち早くキー入力を取得したいのです。
ドライバ開発からすればシステムの一部としてキー入力を取得できるかもしれませんが、それではアプリケーションを利用できる層は限られています。（管理者でないといけない）
なので、キー入力の仕組みをきちんと理解して、キー入力を取得できるようにしたいのです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問したまま放置するのではなく解決したのであれば承認を、解決していないのであれば何を求めているのか補足をしてください。また[マルチポスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/4236)は嫌われる傾向にあり、回答が集まりにくいことを理解してください。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。https://dixq.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20607 とマルチポストの質問をしています。リンク先のサイト（ミクプラ）でStackOverflowで質問するといいとのアドバイスを頂いたので、質問させていただきます。　ミクプラでは具体的な回答をいただくことができず、未解決の問題となっています。ミクプラでのスレッドは既に締め切っていますのでご安心ください。

Comment: 前半は他サイトについてではなく、本サイトにおける過去の質問についての指摘でした。

Comment: この記事 [Keyloggers: Implementing keyloggers in Windows. Part Two](https://securelist.com/keyloggers-implementing-keyloggers-in-windows-part-two/36358/) が一番広範囲に説明されていると思われます。頑張って読み取ってください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。新しいことばかりで難しいですが、なんとか理解しました。この文中でRawInputThreadの話が出てきていますが、この中でいち早く処理を受けるところはどこなのでしょうか。（kernelmode側から渡されるデータをusermode側でいち早く受け取るところ）「The KeyboardClassServiceCallback procedure extracts a pending termination request from the raw input thread from its queue and returns it with information about the key pressed.」と書かれていますが、KeyboardClassServiceCallback関数はどこに処理を渡すのでしょうか？おそらく、渡し先がusermode側でいち早く処理を受ける場所だと思うのですが...

Comment: Fig.9 に出ていますよ。KeyboardClassServiceCallback は kbdclass.sys 内の処理で、CompletionRoutine に処理を渡します。UserModeで一番早く動くのはAPC(AsynchronousProcedureCall) で、csrss.exe 内の Raw Input Thread が管理する Hardware Input System Queue にデータが入っていきます。

Comment: マルチポスト https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/b17f933e-7583-453c-80ef-9b6b08e98556/windows1239812461125402083721147123951238812356123902594512360123?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissuesja

Answer (score 7):

**コメントから回答化**

一連の流れを図示しているのが、以下の記事の Fig.9 ですね。
**ただし2011年の記事なので、Windows10では何かしらの変更が入っている可能性はあります。**
[Keyloggers: Implementing keyloggers in Windows. Part Two](https://securelist.com/keyloggers-implementing-keyloggers-in-windows-part-two/36358/)

[image: Fig 9: Overview of how Windows processes keyboard input]
Fig 9: Overview of how Windows processes keyboard input

図の中で赤丸の1.1, 1.2, 1.4がそれぞれ以下になります。

> - 1.1. Setting hooks for keyboard messages
> - 1.2. Using cyclical querying of the keyboard
> - 1.4. Using the raw input model

UserModeで一番早いタイミングで読み取れるのは 1.2.の`GetAsyncnKeyState/GetKeyState`ですが、これの呼び出しはキーのUp/Downと連携出来ないので、データを取りこぼすか、頻繁に呼び出して、むやみにシステムの負荷が高くなる、といった可能性が多くなります。

比較的に安定して早いのは、1.4.の`RawInput`でしょう。これに使われる`WM_INPUT`はデフォルトでは通知されないので、明示的に受け取る仕組みを作って動かしておく必要があります。
[Raw Input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/raw-input) / [About Raw Input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/about-raw-input)
[Registration for Raw Input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/about-raw-input#registration-for-raw-input)

> デフォルトでは、アプリケーションは生の入力を受け取りません。デバイスから生の入力を受け取るには、アプリケーションはデバイスを登録する必要があります。

こちらに、複数のキーボードを接続して、特定のキーボードからの入力を無視する仕組みのデモと解説の記事があります。ソフト開発の参考になるでしょう。
[Combining Raw Input and keyboard Hook to selectively block input from multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective)

このデモではRaw Input と keyboard Hookの両方を使っていますが、以下のような注意事項があり、LowLevelKeyboard Hookは使っていません。

> フックに関しては、事はもう少しトリッキーになります。最初にAPIの組み合わせを試していたときは、グローバルなLow Level Keyboard Hook（WH_KEYBOARD_LL）を使おうとしました。問題は、低レベルキーボードフックを使用して何らかの入力をブロックすると（メッセージの進行を止めると）、WindowsはRaw Inputイベントを生成しないことを意味します。つまり、アプリケーションは適切なRaw Input message（WM_INPUT）を取得できません。そのため、Low Level Keyboard Hookを使用することはできませんが、標準のKeyboard Hook（WH_KEYBOARD）を使用する必要があります。これは設定が少し困難です。このフックをグローバルに、つまり実行中のアプリケーションに対して使用したい場合、そのプロシージャは別のDLLモジュール内になければなりません。

ただし、上記のように組み合わせても、メッセージが通知されなかったり、色々と奇妙な現象が発生することが記載されています。注意しておいてください。
[Hook message is missing](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective#Chap5-3)
[Raw Input message is missing](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective#Chap5-4)
[Yet more oddities](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective#Chap6)